# Thread concurrency wait() other thread to finish and continue its work

Tags: android, multithreading, jakarta-ee, concurrency, wait

I want to make a thread to wait for another to finish,instead to terminate it,start the second and create another instance of the firt thread.It's right doing so?

```
Thread1 first = new Thread1();
first.start();
while(flag==true){//start while1
first.wait();
Thread2 second = new Thread2();
second.start();
while(second.isAlive()){
Toast toast = new Toast(...WORKING IN PROGRESS...);//just show something
}
flag = false;
}//end of while1
```

Will the Thread first wait untill the Thread second will stop to run?? I just want Thread first paused and continue working after thread second has finished to run. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
class Worker implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        int count = 0;
        while(true){
            Toast toast = new Toast(...WORKING IN PROGRESS...);//just show something
            count++;

            if(count == 10)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just pass the runnable `Worker` into the thread:

```
Thread first = new Thread(new Worker());
first.start();
first.join();// waits for the first thread to finish
Thread second = new Thread(new Worker());
second.start();
```

Please also note that unless you make a class called `Worker` and `Worker2`, those will not exist. However, there is very little reason to execute one thread, wait for it to finish and then execute another thread: it totally defeats the purpose of concurrency and you might as well just execute the code sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're writing Java, you can use the Thread.join() method to force some thread to wait for another to end. For example, If you want Thread 1 to wait until Thread 2 finishes:

```
Thread Thread2 = new SomethingImplementingThread();
Thread Thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public Thread waitforthisone;
                  public void run() {
                     try {
                     waitforthisone.join();
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                     // Do stuff once waitforthisone has finished
                  });

Thread1.waitforthisone = Thread2;
Thread2.start();
Thread1.start(); // When thread 1 starts it will run Thread 2's join function, and thus 
                 // wait for thread 2 to exit
```

NB: The wait command in your code will cause the thread running (neither thread1 or thread 2 in this case, but the thread that creates them) to wait() [line 4], that is go to sleep. Specifically, the thread waiting can only be woken up if another thread (thread1 or thread2) calls first.notify(). The code you've presented above will never get past line 4 otherwise.

Comment: I am very bad in explaining myself.sorry. I started a thread which is constanly connecting to a server each 2/3 second checking if there are messages for him,saying that it is still available as a client because it offer services too.It works fine.Now i implemented an button with onclickListener,I want to pause the thread and start another which want to connect to the server to send it a request(example a bitmap to be converted). this thread after sent request and received answer ok,just stop. now i want the first thread continue its work checking if there are results or data for the client.

Comment: thead 1 should never die unless with the button exit in which I setted  it's flag on false and finish() to close the mainActivity Thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to synchronize threads -- one of my favorite ways is with a `CountdownLatch` -- but your code shows a lack of understanding of how to use them. I'd suggest reading up a bit more on Threads in general before moving forward. Threads and concurrency are very easy to screw up royally if you do it wrong.